# Sql select query taking too long

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have hosting of SQL Server on Arvixe.

A simple select query of 10000 rows is taking 3 seconds on average. The table do not have to many columns, 10 maybe.

Table is used for transporter companies data and index is primary key of `id_Transporter`.

Does somebody knows what is causing trouble?

I just need to know is maybe location of Arvixe server which is in USA problem, because I am calling it from Serbia.

Sorry for bad English and thanks!

Comment: This is utterly impossible to answer, without seeing **anything at all** - no table structure, no sample data, and most importantly: the **code** for the queries!!

Comment: 10000 rows from USA to Serbia, I thik 3 seconds are quite good.

Comment: I agree with marc_s, it could be something simple (i.e. retrieving all columns, when one column is a blob) or it could be a where clause that could be optimized.

Comment: The select only affects one table? is this SQL Server being queried by several sources?

Comment: Do you use where clause to filter your data?

Comment: Also do not expect miracles in terms of performance from a low cost shared hosting.

Comment: Your fastest query will be `SELECT TOP 10000 * from MyTable`. Use it as a benchmark. Try logging on to server remotely to run queries directly on the server to exclude row data tranfer to your pc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on such a low amount of information, I can just point out some of the common causes of bad query performance:

- The primary key is a string instead of an integer number.
- Not including appropriate filters into the 'where' clause.
- You are querying some columns you don't really need.

In order to improve query performance, you can create an index.

You can also read this [article about improving query performance of databases](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/database-query-performance).

Comment: In addition to your point, More index, will bring less performance, and String Primary Key with Numbers..!